# Finding the maximum likelihood estimator given a special variance

Tags: time-series, variance, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Assuming that $x_t\sim N(0,\sigma_t^2)$, where $\sigma_t^2=\mu+\beta\sigma_t^2+\alpha x_{t-1}^2$

In this case, what is the likelihood function given the sample data $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_T)$?

I understand how to solve the typical MLE for a normal distribution by referring to this https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/normal-distribution-maximum-likelihood but I cannot seem to get the idea on how to solve one with a $\sigma_t^2$ related to $x_{t-1}^2$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting.

Comment: It looks like there must be a typo at the outset, because you attempt to define $\sigma_t^2$ in terms of itself.  Please confirm or fix that.